# real analysis book question

Tags: real-analysis

This is a problem from my analysis book:

If {${x_n}$}, {${y_n}$} are two sequences of zeros and ones, show that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n/2^n=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}y_n/2^n$$
if and only if there is an integer $n$ such that $x_k=0$ and $y_k=1$ for all $k\geq{n}$.

Is this question a typo- don't other conditions need to be imposed?  I know there's been a couple typos in this book already and I don't want to keep spending time on a problem that has an error.

Comment: The "only if" direction is true provided that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ are *distinct* sequences.  Otherwise we could have $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$, with neither eventually constant.  Obviously, you need more for the "if direction."

Comment: Suppose every x_n =y_n. Then the series are certainly equal but there is no reson for either of your conditions to hold,

Comment: Apart from saulspatz comment  it should also be noted that we can have $x_k=1$ and $y_k=0$ for all $k \geq n$.  The result is correct but it is badly worded.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\sum \frac {x_n} {2^{n}}=\sum \frac {y_n} {2^{n}}$. Multiply by $2$ and take the integer part . We get $x_1=y_1$ unless EITHER

$\frac {x_2} 2+\frac {x_3} {2^{2}}+..$ (which belongs to $[0,1]$) becomes $1$ and this is  possible only when  $x_2=x_3=....=1$ and $y_2=y_3...=0$

OR

$\frac {y_2} 2+\frac {y_3} {2^{2}}+..$ (which belongs to $[0,1]$) becomes $1$ and this is possible only when  $y_2=y_3=....=1, x_2=x_3=...=0$.

A repetition of this argument shows that there are only three possibilities:

a) $x_n=y_n$ for all $n$

b) there exists $n$ such that $x_k=1, y_k=0$ for all $k \geq n

c) there exists $n$ such that $y_k=1,x_k=0$ for all $k \geq n